# What is the proper way of putting a tab-delimited database into a dataset?

Tags: hdf5

The file has 26 columns and a very large number of rows. Would the proper way, using HDF5, be to read the file one line at a time, reading the contents into a 1x26 memory space, and then extending the dataset by 1x26 and copying the memory space contents to the dataset's newly added row?

I not sure how efficient this would be or even if this is the right way to do it, I am really new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how rows it will have beforehand?

Comment: Not unless I use a command to get the number of lines beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty dependent on your exact use case. It's certainly not *wrong* to do it the way you suggest, but it is possible there are more efficient/faster ways of doing it. In general, you're going to want to adapt the size of your chunks to how to read/write the data.

If you know roughly the number of rows ahead of time, it's likely to be much quicker to use relatively large chunks with compression. For example, if you know you're likely to have somewhere between 1000 and 2000 rows, then use chunks with 100 rows and enable compression. This will result in much fewer IO operations than a single row at a time.

On the other hand, if the dataset is likely to grow in time, one row at a time, then your way is probably better.

The other consideration is how you're going to read the data. If you're only ever going to read a single row at a time, then 1x26 chunks would be a good idea. If you're going to be reading the whole dataset at once and only a few times, however, use larger chunks.